# Is there any control panel for PHP APCU?

Tags: php, apc

So, I just upgraded to PHP 5.5 on my ubuntu test box and I can save and fetch user cache from apc_* commands along with apcu_* commands (both seem to work)

But when I check the APC backend (the APC control panel) , user cache entries never show up.

Do anyone know about any control panel or a backend where I can check and manage APCU user cache entries in PHP 5.5 ?

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a different script for apcu:

<s>https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/simplify/apc.php</s>

https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/master/apc.php

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/master/apc.php

Answer (score 3):

[APC Admin](http://www.techzonemind.com/apc-admin-new-generation-admin-interface-php-apc/) have newer realtime version, contactable to APCu, only issue is OpCode cache option does not work
[image]